# React Native - Using Expo Audio play a sound at the same time as recording a sound

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, react-native-ios

I'm building an app where a user can record a message while playing background sound effects from a sound board. I'm building the app in React Native using Expo Audio and have almost everything working except that anytime I initiate a Recording using Audio.Recording I have to set 'allowsRecordingIOS' to true and (as described in Expo's documentation) this automatically sets any audio playback after that to play through the earpiece.

If I start a recording, then set that value to false when I play my sound effect, it ends the recording and doesn't mix the two. Any idea how I can override Expo's 'allowRecordingIOS' default behavior of playback through earpiece without ending the recording?

Thanks,

Evan

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @ddmaster It appears that the only solution is to eject out of expo and alter the underlying audio settings. I deprioritized the feature for now.